# Is the [leaving-player] tag a necessary addition?

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice that a 'leaving-player' tag has been added. My personal opinion is that it is unnecessary, but want to try to get a consensus before going ahead and rolling back edits to the questions where it has been added.

Comment: No, it sucks, burn it with fire.

Comment: Although, those questions do reveal that [tag:social] and [tag:groups] seem like inconsistently used synonyms (some have one, others have the other, for no good reason).

Comment: Suggest [leaving-player] synonyms to [groups]? Almost every question about players leaving is about group dynamics/management. It may be a useful synonym to catch people typing `leav` into the tag field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see nothing that the [leaving-player](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaving-player) tag adds that isn't covered by [social](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social), or even things like [problem-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-players) and such if necessary. I believe it's a bit overly specific.

It could lead to a slippery slope of "sub-tags" and eventually we'd have tags like [players-that-smell-bad-and-eat-all-my-chips](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/players-that-smell-bad-and-eat-all-my-chips).

Comment: I endeadened the tag.

Comment: Though there may be a case for [tag:player-hygiene]...

Comment: I'd almost want to support that tag! Not that any of my players have that issue, thankfully.

Answer (score 6):

- Does this tag provide extra context on the question?

  No. How would you even ask this question without putting this information into the question itself?
- Can you be an expert on the topic of "leaving-player?"

  That seems rather too specific.

Comment: I’d be very concerned for someone who claimed that particular expertise...